# My browser cannot find localhost when running VS2017 project and says 'Cannot reach this page'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, localhost, iis-express

I've been making some changes to my MVC project which earlier today was running fine. However, I installed some new software including PostGreSql and npgsql for Visual Studio and now when I run my project it seems IIS can no longer find localhost. The actual message is 'Cannot reach this page. Make sure the web address http://localhost:4068 is correct'.

I've checked that my IIS is running and I've tried deleting my IISExpress folder, deleting the config file in .vs/config but so far nothing seems to work and I don't even know what it was that caused it. If anyone has had this issue, please let me know how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put an entry in your c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts File like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Or simply try http://127.0.0.1:4068 as url

Editing the file needs administrative rights so you might run your editor as administrator.

Comment: sorry didnt read carully enough so i missed the fact that it worked before with localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that your project's properties have changed.

Have you checked the web settings? (right click on project -> properties)

[image]